# How do I create a scope so that I can search acts-as-taggable-on name column with ILIKE and return photo_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

[acts-as-taggable-on gem](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)

In Heroku Console,

> => Photo.find(106).taggings

```
  Photo Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "photos"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 106]]
  Photo Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "photos"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 106]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "taggings".* FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2  [["taggable_id", 106], ["taggable_type", "Photo"]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "taggings".* FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2  [["taggable_id", 106], ["taggable_type", "Photo"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging id: 78, tag_id: 32, taggable_id: 106, taggable_type: "Photo", tagger_id: nil, tagger_type: nil, context: "tags", created_at: "2016-08-11 04:09:55">
```

You can see that there is no `:name` column in `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging` but pay attention to `tag_id: 32`

> => ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(32)

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 32]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 32]]
=> #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 32, name: "pickled", taggings_count: 2>
```

The following code works in the controller:

```
@photos = Photo.approved.tagged_with(params[:tag]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20) if params[:tag].present?
```

but it does not allow for tagged_with to be searched with ILIKE. The tag banana pudding will be returned only if banana pudding is queried.

> Photo.find(106).tag_list

```
  Photo Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "photos"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 106]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  [["taggable_id", 106], ["taggable_type", "Photo"]]
=> ["pickled"]
```

**Edit**

Alternatively, how can I setup my new photo form so that a hidden field :tags copies the tag_list column upon creation?

**Edit for models**

```
=> ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging(id: integer, tag_id: integer, taggable_id: integer, taggable_type: string, tagger_id: integer, tagger_type: string, context: string, created_at: datetime)

=> ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag(id: integer, name: string, taggings_count: integer)

=> Photo(id: integer, user_id: integer, picture: string, title: string, description: string, photo_type: integer, location_type: integer, remote_picture_url: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, approved: boolean, flags_count: integer)
```

**tagging.rb**

```
module ActsAsTaggableOn
class Tagging < ::ActiveRecord::Base #:nodoc:
    belongs_to :tag, class_name: '::ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag', counter_cache: ActsAsTaggableOn.tags_counter
    belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true

    belongs_to :tagger, {polymorphic: true}.tap {|o| o.merge!(optional: true) if ActsAsTaggableOn::Utils.active_record5? }

    scope :owned_by, ->(owner) { where(tagger: owner) }
    scope :not_owned, -> { where(tagger_id: nil, tagger_type: nil) }

    scope :by_contexts, ->(contexts) { where(context: (contexts || 'tags')) }
    scope :by_context, ->(context = 'tags') { by_contexts(context.to_s) }

    validates_presence_of :context
    validates_presence_of :tag_id

    validates_uniqueness_of :tag_id, scope: [:taggable_type, :taggable_id, :context, :tagger_id, :tagger_type]

    after_destroy :remove_unused_tags

    private

    def remove_unused_tags
      if ActsAsTaggableOn.remove_unused_tags
        if ActsAsTaggableOn.tags_counter
          tag.destroy if tag.reload.taggings_count.zero?
        else
          tag.destroy if tag.reload.taggings.count.zero?
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**tag.rb**

```
#encoding: utf-8
module ActsAsTaggableOn
class Tag < ::ActiveRecord::Base

    ### ASSOCIATIONS:

    has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy, class_name: '::ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging'

    ### VALIDATIONS:

    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_uniqueness_of :name, if: :validates_name_uniqueness?
    validates_length_of :name, maximum: 255

    # monkey patch this method if don't need name uniqueness validation
    def validates_name_uniqueness?
      true
    end

    ### SCOPES:
    scope :most_used, ->(limit = 20) { order('taggings_count desc').limit(limit) }
    scope :least_used, ->(limit = 20) { order('taggings_count asc').limit(limit) }

    def self.named(name)
      if ActsAsTaggableOn.strict_case_match
        where(["name = #{binary}?", as_8bit_ascii(name)])
      else
        where(['LOWER(name) = LOWER(?)', as_8bit_ascii(unicode_downcase(name))])
      end
    end

    def self.named_any(list)
      clause = list.map { |tag|
        sanitize_sql_for_named_any(tag).force_encoding('BINARY')
      }.join(' OR ')
      where(clause)
    end

    def self.named_like(name)
      clause = ["name #{ActsAsTaggableOn::Utils.like_operator} ? ESCAPE '!'", "%#{ActsAsTaggableOn::Utils.escape_like(name)}%"]
      where(clause)
    end

    def self.named_like_any(list)
      clause = list.map { |tag|
        sanitize_sql(["name #{ActsAsTaggableOn::Utils.like_operator} ? ESCAPE '!'", "%#{ActsAsTaggableOn::Utils.escape_like(tag.to_s)}%"])
      }.join(' OR ')
      where(clause)
    end

    def self.for_context(context)
      joins(:taggings).
        where(["taggings.context = ?", context]).
        select("DISTINCT tags.*")
    end

    ### CLASS METHODS:

    def self.find_or_create_with_like_by_name(name)
      if ActsAsTaggableOn.strict_case_match
        self.find_or_create_all_with_like_by_name([name]).first
      else
        named_like(name).first || create(name: name)
      end
    end

    def self.find_or_create_all_with_like_by_name(*list)
      list = Array(list).flatten

      return [] if list.empty?

      existing_tags = named_any(list)

      list.map do |tag_name|
        comparable_tag_name = comparable_name(tag_name)
        existing_tag = existing_tags.find { |tag| comparable_name(tag.name) == comparable_tag_name }
        begin
          existing_tag || create(name: tag_name)
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
          # Postgres aborts the current transaction with
          # PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
          # so we have to rollback this transaction
          raise DuplicateTagError.new("'#{tag_name}' has already been taken")
        end
      end
    end

    ### INSTANCE METHODS:

    def ==(object)
      super || (object.is_a?(Tag) && name == object.name)
    end

    def to_s
      name
    end

    def count
      read_attribute(:count).to_i
    end

    class << self



      private

      def comparable_name(str)
        if ActsAsTaggableOn.strict_case_match
          str
        else
          unicode_downcase(str.to_s)
        end
      end

      def binary
        ActsAsTaggableOn::Utils.using_mysql? ? 'BINARY ' : nil
      end

      def unicode_downcase(string)
        if ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Unicode.respond_to?(:downcase)
          ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Unicode.downcase(string)
        else
          ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars.new(string).downcase.to_s
        end
      end

      def as_8bit_ascii(string)
        if defined?(Encoding)
          string.to_s.dup.force_encoding('BINARY')
        else
          string.to_s.mb_chars
        end
      end

      def sanitize_sql_for_named_any(tag)
        if ActsAsTaggableOn.strict_case_match
          sanitize_sql(["name = #{binary}?", as_8bit_ascii(tag)])
        else
          sanitize_sql(['LOWER(name) = LOWER(?)', as_8bit_ascii(unicode_downcase(tag))])
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: please show your model `photos.rb` , `tagging.rb`, `tags.rb` because I think that a solution with a `.joins` can be solved

Comment: @BrenoPerucchi I added the models above, thank you.